# Android: How can I save image files that are not (JPEG & PNG)? [after rotate]

Tags: android, image, save, rotation, bmp

I am trying to rotate an image from sdcard and then save back to sdcard.

I can do that for ".jpg" format by using ExifInterface class:

```
exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, Integer.toString(orientation));
exif.saveAttributes();
```

For ".png" files, I would have to actually rotate and save:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(degrees);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

What about ".bmp", ".tiff", ".gif" ??

It seems like CompressFormat only supports 'CompressFormat.PNG' and 'CompressFormat.JPG'.

Is this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Limited To JPG , PNG , WEBP

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html

Answer (score -2):

Hey just give the name to .bmp

Do this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
_bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);

//you can create a new file name "test.BMP" in sdcard folder.
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "**test.bmp**")
```

it'll sound that IM JUST FOOLING AROUND but try it once it'll get saved in bmp foramt..Cheers

Comment: File extension is just a convention. It will save PNG image as *test.bmp* but it won't affect compression. I don't even bother with adding file extensions in image cache - use a hash for the file name and whatever compression suits best.